# InvalidArgumentException - View not found

Tags: laravel-5, server

recently I upload my laravel a server program, but from there I can not get into any form, only the grids, this why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your filenames. Different operating systems and software versions work differently. For example: it might not be the same to return 'view.index' and 'view.Index'